# Field being ignored when querying

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have the following document

```
{ 
  "authors" : "Nanna Friis",
  "authorsId" : [ "4642" ],
  "description" : "Med denne praktiske og pædagogiske håndbog kommer du hele vejen     rundt om at skrive godt til nettet. Du bliver taget ved hånden og får en grundig gennemgang af de helt særlige præmisser, der hersker på nettet. ",
  "iSBN" : "9788762904118",
  "mediaType" : "10",
  "name" : "Kort, klart og klikbart",
  "nameSort" : "Kort, klart og klikbart",
  "price" : 250.0,
  "productId" : "9788762904118",
  "publicationAreaCode" : "3077",
  "tags" : [  ],
  "titleId" : "25004"
}
```

When doing a query like this `http://localhost:9200/titles/_search?q=Nanna*` i don't get any results. If i instead query on ie. the productId like this `http://localhost:9200/titles/_search?q=9788762904118` im getting the document in question.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not specify the query field in the request

in such case you will search the [Default Search Field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html)

> When not explicitly specifying the field to search on in
>   the query string syntax, the index.query.default_field will be used to
>   derive which field to search on. It defaults to _all field.
>
> So, if _all field is disabled, it might make sense to change it to set
>   a different default field.

Comment: i don't remember ever changing default search field, and for sure didn't set it explicitly to productId, which is the field that the example-query matches. Searching for "Kort, klart og klikbart" also returns this particular document, so it seems like it knows how to search across the fields, just not "authors" :/

Comment: these are examples of exact matches, if you search for "Nanna Friis", I assume that it will also find it. Just make sure that all the searchable fields are of type string with index analyzed property and may be you also want to use the Danish stemmer filter. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/stemmer-tokenfilter.html

Comment: Actually searching for "Nanna Friis" doesn't yield this particular document, but instead a document that has the following name value "Festskrift til Orla Friis Jensen". So it does know how to search for not-exact matches as well, just not in the authors field :/

Comment: Okay, i'll accept this as the correct answer since it helped me somewhat on the way in digging down to the root cause. Which was in the mapping (which i didn't originally create), where the authors field had the include_in_all setting set to false.